# How can I judge whether deep freeze is in frozen programatically?

Tags: software-design, auto-update, deepfreeze

Two problem here:

1. Just like the title, when Faronics' deep freeze is running at my computer, how can I find whether it is in frozen state programatically?
2. Deep freeze seriously influence my software update scheme, Is there any good idea to handle it?

Any answer is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found it by searching the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Faronics\Deep Freeze 6\DF Status
```

This will be either `Frozen` or `Thawed` as a string.

An oddity is the fact that it says Deep Freeze 6 in the registry but i have version 8 installed.

Comment: Confirmed the key path is correct on `8.53.220.5445`. PowerShell query:
`(Get-ItemProperty 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Faronics\Deep Freeze 6').'DF Status'`

Answer (score 1):

You can query windows event log for checking Deep Freeze frozen or thawed state.

When Deep Freeze is in Frozen state it will create an event log under

**Event Logs > Windows > Application**

**Event Data : Frozen**

When Deep Freeze is in Thawed state it will create an event log under

**Event Logs > Windows > Application**

**Event Data : Thawed**

Comment: Windows 10. Nothing about thawed or frozen in there i restarted multiple times. I found in System there's a log that says "Read from record ID 23." not really useful but it's source is DeepFrz

Answer (score -1):

First Question:

Hold down the shift key and double-click the Deep Freeze icon. Alternatively, you can press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F6.

Enter your password and click OK.(ask the shop owner)
If you have not yet entered a password you should be able to click OK without entering a password.

The Boot Options dialog is displayed. That will tell you if it's active.

Second Question:

Deep Freeze is not optimized to handle updates. I've tried a few different solutions similar to Deep Freeze and found that Drive Vaccine was the most user friendly in terms of implementing updates. Something to keep in mind, as I know the handling of updates has been many people's biggest complaint about Deep Freeze.

Comment: how i can check first question programmatically, i want to check whether deep freeze is in frozen in my application. thanks any way.